# Access Card Members in Trello Powerup Card Button Popup

Tags: trello, trello-powerup

We are building a Trello Powerup to capture feedback information into a separate set of services (Rails app). To do this we have a [Card button](https://developers.trello.com/power-ups/capabilities#card-buttons) that creates a popup for an iframe similar to the example found in [`card-buttons` capabilities](https://developers.trello.com/power-ups/capabilities#card-buttons).

As part of this iframe, we'd like the Trello Powerup user to see and check card members. Unfortunately, in the iframe we only have the `cid` or card id.

The only way we see to do this nicely is to use the [Trello Card Members API endpoint](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-members) with the `cid`. This would require the user to have OAuthed their Trello account with our site/service. Totally possible, but not the greatest experience.

Another option might be query string, but it's ugly. Using the [`card` data method](https://developers.trello.com/power-ups/client-library) we could encode each member's `avatarHash`, `user_id`, and `fullName` in the iframe url.

Are these the only options? Can I add new data to the iframe `context`?

Answer (score 0):

card-buttons automatically use `t.signUrl`, so there is no opportunity to add arguments to the data Trello automatically sends. It is possible, however, to access the `t` variable `t` variable through the `iframe()` method.

I haven't tried this code (although I know without `t.sizeTo('#page');` the attachment section will have a scrollbar), but it should work in your iframe:

```
var t = TrelloPowerUp.iframe();
t.card('members').then(function (values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: On a side note, I can't figure out how to access data like members or even the card name for use in `TrelloPowerUp.initialize()`. The `t` object only appears to be available inside `initialize()`, (`iframe()` isn't accessible here) and you can't return data from a promise such as `t.card('name');`. I'd love to hear feedback on that issue if anyone has some.